# jQuery: replace with the selected/highlighted text?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a very simple text editor using jquery.

I can get the selected/highlightet texts. and I can also wrap it in `<strong>text text</strong>` as well.

However, when i append it into the div again, it doesn't replace the highlighted text. it just appends it to the current texts.

To explain this better, i've created this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/5502/

and this is my jquery code:

```
$('#showBold').on('click', function(e){

e.preventDefault();

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}


var header = getSelectionText();



var boldHeader = header.replace(header, '<strong>'+header+'</strong>');


$('#details00').append(boldHeader);


});
```

Select the texts in the Div and click on the button to see the issue.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: "it just appends it to the current texts."  the last line reads $('#details00').APPEND(......

Comment: @ProgrammerV5, correct but the line before the last line says `header.replace(`

Comment: And that returns something.....but then you APPEND to the DIV (the DIV is the actual one getting the content so you should val instead of append.

Comment: @ProgrammerV5, val will replace the entire content as opposed to append the changes! or am I missing something?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/5503/ this? Anyway, I will look at what you want to do differently. Start looking at document.body.contentEditable = true that'll give you a pointer.

Comment: that is close, yes, but the `<strong>` tags are showing inside the html. i tried to replace the `text()` with `html()` in your code but there seems to be a bug somewhere because it wont work! is there a particular reason you would do it differently or its just a personal preference ?

Comment: From what you are saying you want basically a small HTML editor, there are thousands of those out there, and there are several issues that those products already worked on, I will suggest you to take a look at those. It will save you tons of time (ckeditor is the latest I've used on a project)

Comment: @ProgrammerV5, as i mentioned in my question, I need to create my own editor. it would've been far easier to use an out of the box one if i could but i cant.

Comment: I see, that happens. I think that there is a good answer down below you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with just text replacement. The selection API lets you modify the contents of the selection, so making the selected text bold is not that hard:

```js
var $textarea = $('#textarea');

$('#bold').on('click', function(e){
 var selection = window.getSelection();

 // Make sure something was selected
 if (!selection.rangeCount) {
  return;
 }

 var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
 var $container = document.createElement('b');

 // Move the contents of the selection into the container
 $container.appendChild(range.extractContents());

 // Move the container into the now empty range
 range.insertNode($container);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="bold">Make Bold</button>
<div id="textarea" contenteditable>Content Here....</div>
```

There are a bunch of corner cases and bugs that you have to account for, however, so you may want to just use some pre-built rich text editor.

Comment: is there anyway to toggle() the bold? example: click a button once and it makes the selection bold and then click it again and it will remove the bold?

Comment: @DavidHope: Sure, but that's outside of the scope of this question. Look at [Range.commonAncestorContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/commonAncestorContainer).