# How to take and replace text in a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I take and replace text on a webpage like to extract all the text in elements from a webpage, similar to how Google Translate does it.
It needs to remember where these contents are at, replace their positions with some kind of text of my own.
I am unsure of what API if any there are to do this.

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374459/jquery-replace-with-the-selected-highlighted-text

Comment: you have to use JavaScript, not API

Comment: @Aishwarya
I have looked at some basic code that walks a DOM, but what I need is something that scrapes the contents and appends it to some format that I can then use to replace it back.
Ideally I was hoping to get something like how google translate extracts and replaces text, or perhaps an api that does it that I can utilise/import

Comment: you can use this api ,plz check https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Selecting-Replacing-Text-textrange/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this. This script is similar to google translate:

```js
[... document.querySelectorAll("*")].forEach(ele=>{

if(ele.nodeName == 'SCRIPT' ||ele.nodeName == 'STYLE'){return;} //don't want to replace script and style tags

if(ele.innerHTML != "" & ele.querySelectorAll("*").length==0){ //check for element inside element 
  ele.innerHTML = "myHtml"; //replace with your html
}
});
```

```html
<div><div>text</div><div><div>text</div></div></div>
<script>
document.body.style.background = "red";
</script>
```